# Can i store a UInt32, Int32 and a float value inside a double without losing information?

Tags: c#, double, type-conversion, precision, ieee-754

I need to save UInt32, Int32 and float values inside a variable. Can I use `double` without losing information (e.g. losing some digits in the conversion) or do I need to use a arbitrary precision class?

From my current research it seems I can, as I can store the maximum value of UInt32 without loosing information:

```
Assert.AreEqual(UInt32.MaxValue, Convert.ToUInt32(Convert.ToDouble(UInt32.MaxValue)));
```

- Therefore double should support enough digits to represent all numbers smaller   or equal to UInt32.MaxValue.
- Int32 has anyway a smaller value range, so it is also supported.
- Float should also be supported as it just double with less precision.

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Well, you can store them in a [`Decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) : "This type provides methods that convert Decimal values to and from SByte, Int16, Int32, Int64, Byte, UInt16, UInt32, and UInt64 values. Conversions from these integral types to Decimal are widening conversions that never lose information or throw exceptions."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Being able to store the maximum value of `UInt32` without losing information doesn't necessarily mean you'll be able to store *all* values in `UInt32` without losing information - after all, there are plenty of `long` values which *can* be stored in a `double` even though some smaller values can't. (2<sup>62</sup> can easily be stored exactly in a `double`, but 2<sup>62</sup> - 1 can't, for example.)

However, you *are* okay - [the mantissa for `double` is 52-bits long](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx), so any integer with fewer than 52 bits can trivially be stored as value * 2<sup>0</sup> (i.e. an effective scale of 0).

And yes, `float` values can be converted to `double` with no loss of precision too.

However, note that this doesn't mean that `0.1f == 0.1d` for example - it just means that `(double) 0.1f` is exactly the same number as `0.1f`, in a different representation.

It's also worth noting that `Int32` doesn't have a smaller range than `UInt32` - they both have a range of exactly 2<sup>32</sup> consecutive values. However, `Int32` *does* have a smaller "absolute" value, and with the way that sign is represented in floating point values, that's relevant. You still actually need 32 bits in order to store the absolute value of every `Int32`, because `Int32.MinValue` is -10000...0000 in binary (32 bits in total), or -(2<sup>31</sup> + 1).

Finally, `float` isn't just `double` with less precision - it's got a smaller range too. It only has 8 bits for the exponent compared with 11 in `double`. So there are numbers well within the range of `double` which are outside the range of `float`, even if they don't have many significant (binary) digits.

Comment: "any integer with fewer than 52 bits can trivially be stored as value * 2^0"

This part of the answer is slightly misleading as the mantissa part doesn't store an integer but a binary fraction between 1 and 2. You do need to use a non-zero exponent in order to move the point to the correct place when representing integers in floating point.

Comment: @JoanCharmant: Considering as an integer or a binary fraction is merely a matter of a different perspective on how far it's shifted. I find it simpler to consider as an integer; YMMV. I certainly think it's simpler to think of a value which has an integer result as an integer scaled by 0 than as a binary fraction scaled... that's why I've talked about it as an *effective* scale. The details of what the bit pattern of the exponent is, along with normalization, isn't relevant here except in working out the *precise* point at which integers can no longer be exactly represented.